# Error 302 with download_data in appcfg.py on App Engine / Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I'm trying to download all of the entities of a particular Kind from my App Engine application (Python).

```
appcfg.py download_data 
    --email=[myemail] 
    --url http://[myapp].appspot.com/remote_api 
    --filename [datafile].csv 
    --kind [MyEntity] 
    --config_file /path/to/bulkloader.yaml 
    --noisy 
    --oauth2_refresh_token=token 
    /path/to/myapp/
10:33 PM Application: [myapp]
10:33 PM Downloading data records.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20160726.223325
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-progress-20160726.223325.sql3
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-results-20160726.223325.sql3
[DEBUG   ] [WorkerThread-0] WorkerThread: started
[DEBUG   ] [WorkerThread-1] WorkerThread: started
[DEBUG   ] [WorkerThread-2] WorkerThread: started
[DEBUG   ] [WorkerThread-3] WorkerThread: started
[DEBUG   ] [WorkerThread-4] WorkerThread: started
[DEBUG   ] [WorkerThread-5] WorkerThread: started
[DEBUG   ] [WorkerThread-6] WorkerThread: started
[DEBUG   ] [WorkerThread-7] WorkerThread: started
[DEBUG   ] [WorkerThread-8] WorkerThread: started
[DEBUG   ] [WorkerThread-9] WorkerThread: started
[DEBUG   ] Configuring remote_api. url_path = /remote_api, servername = [myapp].appspot.com
2016-07-26 22:33:25,999 INFO client.py:546 Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token 
2016-07-26 22:33:25,999 INFO client.py:804 Refreshing access_token 
Error 302: --- begin server output ---

--- end server output ---
```

remote_api is configured in app.yaml:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
builtins:
- remote_api: on
```

(And this works, because I was able to use the Remote API shell to access my application.)

My bulkloader.yaml file was just generated, so there's no problem there.  And as you can see above I used the --noisy flag and there's still very little information.

I'd love any help in figuring out what exactly is going on here!

Comment: The error message is not very talky. But in the scope of HTTP a 302 is not an error but a redirect.

Comment: Yep, but I suspect it's not an HTTP error.